# How to add $value to Odata query with multiple parameters

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have an oData service for File Download functionality. I have to include `$value` parameter to oData call to trigger `GET_Stream` at backend.

I am able to do it, if I have single parameter. When I have multiple parameters, I am not sure how to append `$value` to query. Kindly assist.

```
"/FileDownloadXXX?DirectoryName="+this.getView().getModel().getData().results[temp].DirectoryName+"&FileName="+aSelectedItems[i].getProperty("fileName")+"/$value"
```

Tried by setting the parameters as above, But in network tab, I don't see `$value` appended.

Comment: Not sure why this should not work but maybe try appending the parameters after the /$value, so `/abc('z')/$value?x=a&y=b`

Comment: if I append $value before parameters, then I get an error saying FileDownloadXXX is not of GET_Entity type and is of type GET_EntitySet @pguddi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
var sDirectory = this.getView().getModel().getData().results[temp].DirectoryName;
var sFilename = aSelectedItems[i].getProperty("fileName");
var sUrl = "/FileDownload(DirectoryName='" + sDirectory + "',FileName='" + sFilename + "')/$value";
```